# Installing TexLive 2013 with starlinq instructions

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, latex, texlive

I'm following [this guide](http://starlinq.livejournal.com/3616.html) on how to install TeX Live on Ubuntu 12.04 (and I'm trying to install TeX Live **2013**, not 2012.). I want to install all the packages (except for the language support, I just need English (UK)).

In this section it starts getting vague:

```
Setting environment variables

Add new paths to your environment variables. In ~/.profile add finally the lines:


PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH


Finally do the MANPATH mapping, open the terminal and type

$ sudo gedit /etc/manpath.config

Find the section with # set up PATH to MANPATH mapping. At the end of this section add the following line.

MANPATH_MAP     /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux    /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man

Now we can close the gedit window.
```

Where exactly do I add the `PATH`,`MANPATH`,`INFOPATH` lines in the `profile` file? Right at the bottom?

The `MANPATH_MAP` line doesn't exactly fit neatly in the predefined columns in this section, so does the amount of spacing in

```
MANPATH_MAP     /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux    /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man
```

actually matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append that lines to `~/.profile` - that means to add them at the end of the file.

There is nothing wrong if `MANPATH_MAP` doesn't fit in the predefined columns.

If you are afraid of messing things up make a backup of the files you're modifying.

Comment: Thanks. Is it necessary to do an update immediately after installation (as in the instructions)? My internet connection is a little dodgy.

Comment: @MedullaOblongata Generally speaking software updates are recommended because they may fix bugs, add new features. But if everything work as expected there is no rush to do an update.